# Images take a very long time to load in C#

Tags: c#

The problem I have it is:

I tried to download 1000+ images -> it works, but it takes a very long time to load the image downloaded completely, and the program continues and downloads the next image etc... Until let's admit 100 but the 8th image is still not finished downloading.

So I would like to understand why I encounter such a problem here and / or how to fix this problem.

Hope to see an issue

```
private string DownloadSourceCode(string url)
{
    string sourceCode = "";

    try
    {
        using (WebClient WC = new WebClient())
        {
            WC.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            WC.Headers.Add("Accept", "image / webp, */*");
            WC.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "fr, fr - FR");
            WC.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=1");
            WC.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
            WC.Headers.Add("Origin", url);
            WC.Headers.Add("TE", "Trailers");
            WC.Headers.Add("user-agent", Fichier.LoadUserAgent());

            sourceCode = WC.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            string status = string.Format("{0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
            LabelID.TextInvoke(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} ", status,
                                                    ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription,
                                                    ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).Server));
        }
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException a) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(a.Message); 
    }

    return sourceCode;
}

private void DownloadImage(string URL, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient WC = new WebClient())
        {
            WC.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            WC.Headers.Add("Accept", "image / webp, */*");
            WC.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "fr, fr - FR");
            WC.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=1");
            WC.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
            WC.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://myprivatesite.fr//" + STARTNBR.ToString());
            WC.Headers.Add("user-agent", Fichier.LoadUserAgent());

            WC.DownloadFile(URL, filePath);

            NBRIMAGESDWLD++;
        }

        STARTNBR = CheckBoxBack.Checked ? --STARTNBR : ++STARTNBR;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        LabelID.TextInvoke("Accès non autorisé au fichier");
    }
    catch (WebException e) 
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            LabelID.TextInvoke(string.Format("{0} / {1} / {2} ", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode,
                                                                        ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription,
                                                                        ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).Server));
        }
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException a) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(a.Message); 
    }
}

private void DownloadImages()
{
    const string URL = "https://myprivatesite.fr/";

    string imageIDURL = string.Concat(URL, STARTNBR);

    string sourceCode = DownloadSourceCode(imageIDURL);

    if (sourceCode != string.Empty)
    {
        string imageNameURL = Fichier.GetURLImage(sourceCode);

        if (imageNameURL != string.Empty)
        {
            string imagePath = PATHIMAGES + STARTNBR + ".png";
            LabelID.TextInvoke(STARTNBR.ToString());
            LabelImageURL.TextInvoke(imageNameURL + "\r");

            DownloadImage(imageNameURL, imagePath);

            Extension.SaveOptions(STARTNBR, CheckBoxBack.Checked);
        }
    }

    STARTNBR = CheckBoxBack.Checked ? --STARTNBR : ++STARTNBR;
}

// END FUNCTIONS

private void BoutonStartPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Fichier.RGBIMAGES != null)
    {
        if (boutonStartPause.Text == "Start")
        {
            boutonStartPause.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            boutonStartPause.Text = "Pause";

            if (myTimer == null)
                myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => new Task(DownloadImages).Start(), null, 0, Trackbar.Value);
        }
        else if (boutonStartPause.Text == "Pause")           
            EndTimer();

        Extension.SaveOptions(STARTNBR, CheckBoxBack.Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code download 1 image or several images? I can't really see how it's enumerating through each image.

Comment: Opening 1000 connections at once isn't going to work, you'd have to pool them, 2-4 download at once is usually enough to max the network connection.

Comment: @KingOfArrows OP is using timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer

Comment: Create one HttpClient so it can reuse tcp / ssl connections. That alone would make a drastic difference.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577032/why-images-be-soo-long-to-load-c-sharp). It seems likely that you and `user15954938` are the same person and that you've violated the site rules by reposting the same closed question rather than improving the question so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I would like to understand why I encounter such a problem here and / or how to fix this problem.

There are probably two reasons I can think of.

- Connection/Port Exhaustion
- Thread Pool Exhaustion

**Connection/Port Exhaustion**
This happens when you're attempting to create too many connections at once, or when the connections you made previously have not yet been released. When you use a [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0) the resources it uses sometimes don't get released immediately. This causes a delay between when that object is disposed and the actual time that the next [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0) attempting to use the same port/connection actually gets access to that port.

An example of something that would most likely cause **Connection/Port Exhaustion**

```cs
int i = 1_000;
while(i --> 0)
{
    using var Client = new WebClient();
        // do some webclient stuff
}
```

When you create a lot of web clients, which is sometimes necessary due to the inherent lack of concurrency in `WebClient`. There's a possibility that by the time the next `WebClient` is instantiated, the port that the last one was using may not be available yet, causing either a delay(while it waits for the port) or *worse* the next `WebClient` opening another port/connection. This can cause a never ending list of connections to open causing things to grind to a halt!

**[Thread Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool#thread-pool-characteristics) Exhaustion**
This is caused by trying to create too many `Task` or `Thread` objects at once that block their own execution(via [`Thread.Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-5.0) or a long running operation).

Normally this isn't an issue since the built in [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0) does a really good job of keeping track of a lot of tasks and makes sure that they all get turns to execute their code.

Where this becomes a problem is the `TaskScheduler` has no context for which tasks are important, or which tasks are going to need more time than others to complete. So therefor when many tasks are processing long running operations, blocking, or throwing exceptions, the `TaskScheduler` has to wait for those tasks to finish before it can start new ones. If you are particularly unlucky the `TaskScheduler` can start a bunch of tasks that are all blocking and **no tasks can start**, *even if all the other tasks waiting are small and would complete instantly*.

You should generally use as few tasks as possible to increase reliability and avoid thread pool exhaustion.

**What you can do**
You have a few options to help improve the reliability and performance of this code.

- Consider using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) instead. I understand you may be required to use `WebClient` so I have provided answers using `WebClient` exclusively.
- Consider Requesting multiple downloads/strings within the same task to avoid Thread Pool Exhaustion
- Consider using a `WebClient` helper class that limits the available webclients that can be active at once, and has the ability to keep webclients open if you're going to be accessing the same website multiple times.

**`WebClient` Helper Class**
I created a **very** simple helper class to get you started. This will allow you to create `WebClient` requests asynchronously without having to worry about creating too many clients at once. The default limit is the number of Cores in the client's processor(this was chosen arbitrarily).

```cs
public class ConcurrentWebClient
{
    // limits the number of maximum clients able to be opened at once
    public static int MaxConcurrentDownloads => Environment.ProcessorCount;

    // holds any clients that should be kept open

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebClient> Clients;

    // prevents more than the alloted webclients to be open at once
    public static readonly SemaphoreSlim Locker;

    // allows cancellation of clients
    private static CancellationTokenSource TokenSource = new();

    static ConcurrentWebClient()
    {
        Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebClient>();

        Locker ??= new SemaphoreSlim(MaxConcurrentDownloads, MaxConcurrentDownloads);
    }

    // creates new clients, or if a name is provided retrieves it from the dictionary so we don't need to create more than we need
    private async Task<WebClient> CreateClient(string Name, bool persistent, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // try to retrieve it from the dictionary before creating a new one
        if (Clients.ContainsKey(Name))
        {
            return Clients[Name];
        }

        WebClient newClient = new();

        if (persistent)
        {
            // try to add the client to the dict so we can reference it later
            while (Clients.TryAdd(Name, newClient) is false)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // allow other tasks to do work while we wait to add the new client
                await Task.Delay(1, token);
            }
        }

        return newClient;
    }

    // allows sending basic dynamic requests without having to create webclients outside of this class
    public async Task<T> NewRequest<T>(Func<WebClient, T> Expression, int? MaxTimeout = null, string Id = null)
    {
        // make sure we dont have more than the maximum clients open at one time
        // 100s was chosen becuase WebClient has a default timeout of 100s
        await Locker.WaitAsync(MaxTimeout ?? 100_000, TokenSource.Token);

        bool persistent = true;

        if (Id is null)
        {
            persistent = false;
            Id = string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
            WebClient client = await CreateClient(Id, persistent, TokenSource.Token);

            // run the expression to get the result
            T result = await Task.Run<T>(() => Expression(client), TokenSource.Token);

            if (persistent is false)
            {
                // just in case the user disposes of the client or sets it to ull in the expression we should not assume it's not null at this point
                client?.Dispose();
            }

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            // make sure even if we encounter an error we still
            // release the lock
            Locker.Release();
        }
    }

    // allows assigning the headers without having to do it for every webclient manually
    public static void AssignDefaultHeaders(WebClient client)
    {
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", "image / webp, */*");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "fr, fr - FR");
        client.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=1");
        client.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
        // i have no clue what Fichier is so this was not tested
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", Fichier.LoadUserAgent());
    }

    // cancels a webclient by name, whether its being used or not
    public async Task Cancel(string Name)
    {
        // look to see if we can find the client
        if (Clients.ContainsKey(Name))
        {
            // get a token incase we have to emergency cance
            CancellationToken token = TokenSource.Token;

            // try to get the client from the dictionary
            WebClient foundClient = null;

            while (Clients.TryGetValue(Name, out foundClient) is false)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // allow other tasks to perform work while we wait to get the value from the dictionary
                await Task.Delay(1, token);
            }

            // if we found the client we should cancel and dispose of it so it's resources gets freed
            if (foundClient != null)
            {
                foundClient?.CancelAsync();

                foundClient?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    // the emergency stop button
    public void ForceCancelAll()
    {
        // this will throw lots of OperationCancelledException, be prepared to catch them, they're fast.
        TokenSource?.Cancel();
        TokenSource?.Dispose();
        TokenSource = new();

        foreach (var item in Clients)
        {
            item.Value?.CancelAsync();
            item.Value?.Dispose();
        }

        Clients.Clear();
    }
}
```

**Request Multiple Things at Once**
Here all I did was switch to using the helper class, and made it so you can request multiple things using the same connection

```cs
public async Task<string[]> DownloadSourceCode(string[] urls)
{
    var downloader = new ConcurrentWebClient();

    return await downloader.NewRequest<string[]>((WebClient client) =>
    {
        ConcurrentWebClient.AssignDefaultHeaders(client);

        client.Headers.Add("TE", "Trailers");

        string[] result = new string[urls.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
        {
            string url = urls[i];

            client.Headers.Remove("Origin");

            client.Headers.Add("Origin", url);

            result[i] = client.DownloadString(url);
        }

        return result;
    });
}
private async Task<bool> DownloadImage(string[] URLs, string[] filePaths)
{
    var downloader = new ConcurrentWebClient();

    bool downloadsSucessful = await downloader.NewRequest<bool>((WebClient client) =>
    {
        ConcurrentWebClient.AssignDefaultHeaders(client);

        int len = Math.Min(URLs.Length, filePaths.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            // side-note, this is assuming the websites you're visiting aren't mutating the headers
            client.Headers.Remove("Origin");

            client.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://myprivatesite.fr//" + STARTNBR.ToString());

            client.DownloadFile(URLs[i], filePaths[i]);

            NBRIMAGESDWLD++;

            STARTNBR = CheckBoxBack.Checked ? --STARTNBR : ++STARTNBR;
        }


        return true;
    });

    return downloadsSucessful;
}
```

Comment: Very relevant remarks (I'm still quite skeptical about "Connection / port exhaustion:".
Why use an "explicit" static constructor for the initialization of some static fields and not others (assignment to the declaration)?
Isn't there always a limitation on Multi-AppDomain apps that repeatedly call the static constructor (explicit and implicit)?

Thanks for everything, it works very well ;)

Comment: Initially the class I wrote in the answer had more functionality and more verbose implementations. I deleted them and downsized at the last minute leaving the weird static constructor(the goal was a Singleton design pattern). There's no particular reason now that a static construct or is needed. Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to leave some implementations to be done as an exercise for the reader, but still provide a working barebones implementation.